# Good digital multimeter

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I need a good multimeter which measures volts, amps, resistance, capacitance and inductance. Does anybody know where I can get one? Also, I have one with milliamps, but can only measure up to 200 milliamps, so I will need one which can go up to 10 amps. Does anybody know where I can get one? if there aren't any with all of them, is there at least one with amps, capacitance, and inductance, because my current one has volts, resistance, and milliamps. Also, I would wish for it to be digital.

Comment: Shopping questions aren't allowed here. Anyways.. there are lots of online electronics stores out there: http://www.farnell.com, http://www.digikey.com, http://www.futureelectronics.com, http://www.tme.eu etc.

Comment: Typically special meters are used to measure inductance.  They often measure capacitance also, and may have a broader range than found in a typical multimeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fluke 170](http://www.fluke.com/Fluke/usen/Digital-Multimeters/Fluke-170.htm?PID=56027) does most of what you want including up to 10 A. It doesn't do inductance. For that as tcrosley said, use a seperate "LCR" meter such as these from [BK Precision](http://www.bkprecision.com/products/component-testers.html#!/lcr-meters).